# If attribute 'is_customizable' = 1 then add custom option to product

Tags: custom-options, products-management, ce-1.8.1.0

I have 18,000 products and they can either be personalized with text or they can't be personalized.  I imported the products with a custom is_customizable field that is either 1 or 0.  Now I'm trying to figure out how to add a custom option, in bulk, to the products where is_customizable is true.  The custom option is going to be a text area called Personalization Text.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to run a dummy controller action which applies the custom option to bulk products. To add a custom option dynamically.. check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7123108/1577396).

Some excerpt code from the above link.

```
 $opt = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_option');
 $opt->setProduct($product);

 $values = array(
             'title'                => $fieldName,
             'type'                => 'field',
             'is_require'        => true
           );

 $product->setHasOptions(1);
 $opt->addOption($values);
 $opt->saveOptions();
 $product->addOption($opt);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by placing an IF statement on your product page.

```
if($_product->yourcustom_attribute == 1): 
ENTER YOUR CODE TO CALL TEXT AREA
endif;
```

Comment: I was hoping to configure these in Magento with custom options.  I'm not sure how I would call a text area then have the input saved when someone orders a product.